# Unable to use/type letter "d" within terminal on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, command-line, keyboard

While typing the command "gedit" or "cd" or any word which assosicates with the letter "d", it wont come on the screen. Same issue raises while doing a copy paste to the terminal.

**E.G.:** If I copy the following : `cd Desktop` and paste it in the terminal, it becomes `c Desktop`. This happens only in the terminal window but I'm able to type on other windows such as notepad, documents.. etc. How can I solve it?

Comment: I'm no too sure but I suspect that the letter may be using some sort of shortcuts. Just to double check go to **EDIT** > **Keyboard shortcuts** whilst terminal window is active and see whether "D" is been assigned to any.

Comment: no Azer i checked there is no short cuts are assigned

Comment: What terminal are you using? Have you tried some alternative, like `xfce4-terminal`?

Comment: no i am not having any privileges to use alternate terminals

Comment: May I ask what happens when you try to type `d`? any changes happening on the terminal or the pointer? also see whether `D` in caps works?

Comment: nothing is happen if i try to type "d" just the pointer get disappeared but at the same time "D" works

Comment: additional information the terminal executes the "cd" commands which was taken from the history by pressing the up arrow

Comment: did you try changing the font size? this happened to me. d would appear in font sizes 10 and 12 but not 11.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've seen something like this and it was caused by an incorrect readline config. Remove `~/.inputrc`, reopen your shell and try again.

Comment: It's not the same reason then :(

Uhm, this is bizarre. Have you messed with your .bashrc (.zshrc, etc) recently?

Comment: oh ya i just add a single alias into bashrc. is the reason for the problem. i added the following line "export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups" and add a single alias after this

Comment: The HISTCONTROL looks fine. Is the syntax for your alias okay? Try commenting out your changes and see if you still have your problem.

Comment: HISTCONTROL is not my alias.. i refereed a site that has this line before a alias assignment. if this line is not present the alias not working.

Comment: I know the HISTCONTROL is not your alias. What's the alias? Paste it here, please (from the file, not the website where you found it).

Comment: this is mine alias ded="cd Desktop/demo"

Comment: That's not it then. I've no idea. Whatever caused it is most likely something *you* did. Think back on what you changed recently and try reverting those changes one by one.

Comment: @suriyan, on a side note, there's no point in exporting HISTCONTROL.

Comment: but without the export the alias doesn't work